# alert box not working in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I added a stylish alert box to my page, resource is [here](http://csscody.com/demo/jquery-demo/custom-alert-boxes-using-jquery/80/) . But problem is after clicking `ok`, `confirmsubmit.jsp` is not opening. Also in that alert `cancel` button is not appearing why?

javascript

```
  <form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function confirmation() {
    var answer = csscody.alert("Confirm submit?")// added csscody here for alert but after clicking ok nothing happens
    if (answer){

     window.location = "confirmsubmit.jsp";
   }
   else{
     return false;// here cancel button is not coming
   }
     }
   //-->
   </script>
 </form>
```

html

```
 <input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="return confirmation()"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: If i am changing `var answer = csscody.alert("Confirm submit?")` to `confirm("Confirm submit?")` then alert box is coming like normal javascript alert that is without sylish alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

View below code ,it uses button instead of link

```
<form action="confirmsubmit.jsp" method="POST">
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
    $('#btn_submit').click(function(e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    var text = "si o no compa?";
    csscody.confirm(text, {
        onComplete: function(e) {

            if (e) {
                window.location = "confirmsubmit.jsp";
            }
            else {
                return false;

            }


        }

    })
});
}); 
   </script>
   <input type="text" name="textboxname"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" onclick="return confirmation()"/> 
 </form>
```

Comment: `confirm` is not available in csscody, I suppose.

Comment: Just tried my hands around it, what I observed was that `csscody.confirm` does not return anything (true or false) based on what user clicks (OK or Cancel).

Comment: @Chicko yes csscody.confirm is there but i have a button not link. for submit button what event i should use in place of `click`?

Comment: @tom view my latest update, I have changed the code for button instead of link

Answer (score 0):

You willl have to use `confirm` instead of `alert` which will giv eyou both *ok* and *cancel* buttons which return `true` and `false` respectively. And also take off `return` from `onclick`

HTML

```
<form action = "confirmsubmit.jsp" method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "textboxname" />
    <input type = "submit" onclick = "confirmation();" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function confirmation() {
   var answer = confirm("Confirm submit?");
   if (answer){
      window.location = "confirmsubmit.jsp";
   }
   else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok but i want to use that csscody.confirm(); but it is not coming any help please